# Java - References to generic type X should be parameterized

Tags: java

What do I do wrong?
I try to make my code from this perfect working code but in my version I get an error "References to generic type Process1 should be parameterized".
From this line:
Process1 p1 = new Process1(data);

I'm trying to add some fitures from the original code but it is not solving the problem. It seems it has something that I have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare Process1 as a generic type, requiring a type parameter:

```
public class Process1 <T extends SharedData>
```

and therefore when you instantiate a Process1, you need to provide a suitable argument.

Not

```
Process1 p1 = new Process1(data);
```

but

```
Process1<SomeTypeHere> p1 = new Process1<>(someMatchingObject);
```

and in particular

```
Process1<Data> p1 = new Process1<>(data);
```